# How to run "time" on a function in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, time

This works:

```
time ls -l
```

This does not work

```
f() { ls -l }
time f
```

No time output is printed in the second case. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@John1024 gave you the answer for `bash`. I try to answer the `zsh` tag...

You get the timing statistics, if you spawn a subshell for your function:

```
% zsh
% f() { sleep 1 }
% time f
% time (f)
( f; )  0.00s user 0.05s system 4% cpu 1.061 total
% time sleep 1
sleep 1  0.00s user 0.03s system 2% cpu 1.045 total
```

This adds a little overhead, but as you can see from this (non-faked `;)`) example, it's probably insignificant.

Comment: This isn’t obvious from [the documentation of `time`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-timing). Aren’t function invocations also pipelines?

Comment: I noticed that this also applies to built-in functions like `echo`. For example, `time echo abc` prints neither `abc` nor the timing output.

Answer (score 5):

You have tagged this with both `bash` and `zsh`.  This answer applies to `bash`.

This is an error in `bash`:

```
f() { ls -l }
```

What works instead is:

```
f() { ls -l ; }
```

With that new definition of `f`, the `time` command works.

Under `bash`, when grouping commands together in braces, the last command must be followed by a semicolon or a newline.  This is documented under "Compound Commands" in `man bash`.

(I would test this solution under `zsh` but I don't currently have it installed.  But, as per [this SO post,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693515/zsh-how-to-time-a-block-of-code) the solution under `zsh` might be to run `f` in a subshell. *Update: See @mpy's answer for `zsh`.*)

Comment: Even with the semicolon, you don't get a time report in `zsh`.